# simple date visitor counter counting the text lines

Tags: php

i'm trying to make visitors count without sql with simple php code
counting the date list

> i have log file called visits.log contains

```
2018-06-28
2018-06-28
```

only two lines
when i try to echo the lines gives me 5 i donno how but when i try to replace the log with something like

```
test
test
```

gives me 2 visitors

> note: the text file doesn't contain empty space lines.

my php code

```
 <p class="">Views today</p>
<span class=""><?php
$file="../../visitors.log";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
}

fclose($handle);

echo $linecount-1;

 ?></span>
```

my adding lines code

```
$line = date('Y-m-d') . " - $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";
file_put_contents('visitors.log', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: why do you need dates, why not just maintain a counter instead?

Comment: because i have another script that removes old date like if u got 1000 last month visits i can filter more easy with the date

Comment: can your other script can instead reset the counter to zero?

Comment: my script is daily checker and delete old data

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to get number of lines

```
$no_of_lines = count(file($file));
```

Comment: that's the problem it's works well with manually added lines but doesn't work with my add script and it's legit there's no empty lines

Comment: yeah then that script only writes some hidden stuffs. can you post your file writing code here for verification?

Comment: i've updated the question with the adding lines code u can see it's pretty simple code i don't think that code writes hidden thing

Comment: `<?php

$line = date('Y-m-d') . " - $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";
file_put_contents('visitors.log', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
?>
<html>
<body>
<p class="">Views today</p>
<span class=""><?php
$file="visitors.log";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
}

fclose($handle);

echo $linecount-1;

 ?></span>
</body>
</html>
`

Comment: no the last code in index of my site adding visitors ip and date the another code in my admin panel counting the visitors

Comment: and I'm having a file visitors.log in root folder with 777 permission.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help guys  my script was adding a hidden empty lines and i deal with it with `replace()`
replacing the empty lines to remove it